# I want to make a textfield that appears after clicking a button

Tags: flutter, textfield, flutter-onpressed

```
ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom (
                    backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 194, 14, 2)),
                onPressed: () => const Padding (
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
                      child: TextField (
                        decoration: InputDecoration (
                          border: OutlineInputBorder (),
                          hintText: 'Entrer le code ',
                        ),
                      ),

                    ),
                child: const Row (
                  children: [
                    Icon (Icons.edit_document),
                    Text ("Entrer le Code du document"),
                  ],
                )),
```

I tried to insert Textfield on Onpressed action of Elevated Button but is not okay can you help me please?

Comment: *is not ok* is not a problem description, and *can you help me please* is not a specific question. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages, especially [ask] and [mre], to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: you can use a bool on state class. `if(showTextField)TextField()`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st you need to create a bool variable and set it to false

```
Example : isTextFieldShown = false;
```

2nd you need to take a look at the Visibility Widget and set it's property to the bool var that you initiated to false

Example :

```
Visibility(
  visible: isTextFieldShown,
  child: yourTextFieldWidget // here you wrap your textfield widget with the visibility widget like I did
),
```

and finally you need to set the action for your button like this

```
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
          isTextFieldShown = !isTextFieldShown;
                      });
```